# Plotting a line from A to B, but it always ends up vertical

Tags: python, python-3.x

Newbie programmer here trying to plot a line based on the input of 2 coordinates (x0,y0) and (x1,y1). I can't figure out how to work out the angle of the line, so the result is always a vertical line. I think I have a problem in the way I either calculate the angle, or input the angle in the for loop.

Anyone knows what might be wrong with my code?

```
from images import Image

def drawLine(image, x0, y0, x1, y1, red, green, blue):
    image = Image(image)
    color = (red, green, blue)
    a = (y0 - y1)/(x0 - x1)
    xAxis = x1 - x0
    yCount = y0
    for x in range(xAxis):
        image.setPixel(x0,yCount,color)
        yCount = int(yCount + a)
    return image.draw()

def main():
    drawLine("Cat2.gif",25,30,40,60,255,0,0)

main()
```

Here's the result I keep getting: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgCcF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line

```
image.setPixel(x0,yCount,color)
```

to

```
image.setPixel(x,yCount,color)
```

or `x0 + x`, i can't really tell.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you are using the same x value each time in `image.setPixel(x0,yCount,color)`
I am not sure if you meant to put `x0` there but that variable isn't changing every time the for loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

modify your for loop to sth like this:

```
for x in np.arange(x0,x1,0.1):
   image.setPixel(x,(a*x+y0),color)
```

havn't tried running it but it should work!